# Access to the path 'D:\DRR-EA-APP\View' is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am having trouble getting images to display in Crystal report. Then caused the problem as in the picture. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't paste links to images of your `code / error messages`. It would be much better to copy/paste your  `code / error messages` into your question, including what line gives you that error. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Run the Visual Studio as administrator mode and then try.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was happen by permission. Please to look folder permission or IIS.
Or run your IDE as administrator